# How to Initialize arrays of NSString?

Tags: objective-c

What's the easiest / fastest way to initialize an array of `NSString`s in Objective C?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"String1",@"String2",@"String3",nil];
```

Comment: Can I get rid of nil in the end ? I guess not, but why do I have to add it in the end ?

Comment: This just indicates that you have no more elements to add. It's a kind of null terminator I guess.

Comment: @user680406: A function or method with a variable number of arguments doesn't have any way of knowing how many arguments you passed to it (this is just a limitation of the C programming language). So, since NSArray can't contain `nil` anyway, it interprets `nil` as part of a variable argument list to mean "OK, that's all the arguments." This is called a "sentinel value." Without nil to tell it where the arguments end, it wouldn't know any better than to keep walking through memory, trying to treat everything it encounters as an object to be added to the array, until it encountered a 0 or nil.

Answer (score 40):

- C way:

  ```
  NSString *s1, *s2;
  NSString *cArray[]={s1, s2};
  ```

  The size of the cArray is 2, defined by the compiler.
  More info here:
  [How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c)
- NSArray (Objective-C) way:

  ```
  NSArray *objCArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
  ```
- If you are using XCode4 (LLVM4.0 compiler), now you can use NSArray literals:

  ```
  NSArray *array = @[ @"1", @"2" ];
  ```

  More info here: [What are the details of "Objective-C Literals" mentioned in the Xcode 4.4 release notes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347722/what-are-the-details-of-objective-c-literals-mentioned-in-the-xcode-4-4-releas)

Answer (score 12):

NSArray *array = @[@"foo",@"bar"];

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *stringArray[2] = {@"1", @"2"};
```

Comment: So, if I specify the size I don't need to add nil in the end ? Why ?

Comment: The previous answer is for an NSArray, this is for a C array. These are *completely* different, and understanding the difference is pretty much a requirement for objective-c programming.

Comment: Storing objects in a C array is an even iffier proposition than C arrays are in the first place, and that's saying something.

Comment: Telling a newbie developer to create C arrays of NSObjects is very bad advice. The ONLY way this works properly is with string constants created with  a string literal like `@"someString"`.

Comment: If you tried to do this with dynamically allocated `NSString` objects in ARC then the C array would not hold a strong reference to the strings and they would get deallocated when the last strong reference to them went out of scope and the C array would be an array of invalid memory addresses. (An array of "zombies")